# How to capture Emoji from UITextField and pass it as JSON via POST to backend (node.js)

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, nsdictionary, emoji

I'm trying to get user entered text or emoji from a UITextField and store it in a NSMutableDictionary. This NSMutableDictionary is then sent to my backend Server (node.js) via HTTP POST. The backend in turn makes a REST API call out to send the message to the recipient in UTF-8.

This process works perfectly for regular text in Engligh. However if I enter Emoji characters then this fails.

```
NSString *msg = self.textFieldMessage.text;

NSString *test =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:msg encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSString *msgUtf = [msg UTF8String];

NSLog(@"User entered this %@",self.textFieldMessage.text);

NSMutableDictionary *messageData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[messageData setValue:msg  forKey:@"message"];
[messageData setValue:@"testRecipient" forKey:@"recipient"];

[self.textFieldMessage setText:@""];
[self.labelForPush setText:msg];

NSDictionary *temp = [apiCallFromTempViewController sendMessage: messageData];
// this api call does an HTTP POST of the NSMutable Dictionary to my backend
```

It seems to fail when converting the Emoji (NSString) to NSMutableDictionary. Here is the error message in Xcode:

```
Unknown error occured,Please try again later
2015-09-04 02:15:38.822 SecureText[6602:765414] Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x170668a00 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

the HTTP POST received at the backend also reports problems with this call. Here are the errors spit out by my node.js backend:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
   at Object.parse (native)
   at parse (/home/azureuser/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:88:17)
   at /home/azureuser/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:108:18
```

Please advice how to capture the text/emoji in UITextfield and pass it along in NSDictionary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `self.textFieldMessage.text` directly without changing the encoding. `NSString` is valid in JSON as it is and by changing the string encoding you're breaking the emoji.

Comment: Thank you. I was using a simple NSString earlier and have now changed it back.
This morning when I'm looking at my problem, the issue was never at this place. I will post another question as the information I need to provide is significantly different than this one.

I accept your answer as the correct answer for the question I asked.